# SQL Server sequence depending on input id or name

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I want to use different sequences depending which type of number I want to add.

NumberPool

| id | name | description | sequence_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item | items | seq_items |
| 2 | documents | stored documents | seq_docs |

NumberTable

| Number_Type_id | number | more_metadata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo |
| 1 | 2 | bar |
| 1 | 3 | foobar |
| 2 | 1 | barfoo |

Normally, I would first get the sequence for a given number type:

```
SELECT * FROM numberpool 
WHERE NumberPool.name LIKE "item"`
```

-> NumberPool.id = 1, sequence_name= 'seq_item'

```
INSERT INTO NumberTable (Number_Type_id, number,  metadata)
OUTPUT Inserted.number 
VALUES (3, NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.seq_items, 'foo')
```

Is there a way to map the `numberpool.id`?

```
INSERT INTO NumberTable (Number_Type_id, number, metadata)
OUTPUT Inserted.number, Inserted.metadata 
VALUES (3, 'foo')
```

or `numberpool.name` to a sequence?

```
INSERT INTO NumberTable (Number_Type_id, number, metadata)
OUTPUT Inserted.number, Inserted.metadata 
VALUES ('item', 'foo')
```

In that way I would not need to know the ids on the client side. I am unsure if this is a good idea or if my database structure needs some work.

Comment: This sounds like you should have 2 tables, and then you can easily set up the 2 tables to have a different `SEQUENCE` (or just use an `IDENTITY`).

Comment: @Larnu: I have 10 pools and there will be most likely more added in the future.  I just deleted the other pools for easier reading ;)

Comment: Then you need *10* tables, presumably.

Comment: for the ids I could do a subselect inside the insert
`(select ID,sequence_name from NumberPool where name = 'documents')`
But I dont know how to replace the 
`NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.seq_items`
with an subselect

Comment: If you mean a subquery, that would be `(SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.seq_items)` but then you might as well just do `NEXT VALUE FOR DBO.seq_items`... Using the subquery doesn't add anything.